# Case statement in left join

Tags: sql-server

So I have two tables, which both have a `cocnumber` or ChamberOfCommerce-number. This is always a 8-digit number, so e.g. `12345678`. There is a problem though: the first table `aa` has the correct COC numbers of 8-digits, but the second table `bb` has a mix of 11 or 12-digit COC numbers. 11 AND 12-digit numbers have four 0's at the end of the number, which are irrelevant.

Example 11-digit COC:
`12345670000`

Example 12-digit COC: 
`123456780000`

But why are there 11-digit COC numbers? Well, there aren't. What happend is that 11-digit COC numbers should have a `0` in front of them: `0123456780000`, which got cut off when it was stored in the database.

So in the case of a 12-digit COC number, I just cut off the last 4 digits. But for a 11-digit COC number, I have to cut off the last 4 digits AND add a 0 in front of the COC number.

My question is how I would make a CASE statement that performs this manipulation, inside the LEFT JOIN?

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
  aa.cocnumber,
  bb.emloyeesnrtotal AS bb_emloyeesnrtotal

FROM aa
  LEFT JOIN bb ON aa.cocnumber = 
            CASE 
                WHEN LEN(bb.cocnumber) = 12
                    THEN LEFT(bb.cocnumber, 8)
                WHEN LEN(bb.cocnumber) = 11
                    THEN '0' + LEFT(bb.cocnumber, 7)
                END
```

This doesn't seem to produce the correct result though. Can anyone help me point to what I'm doing wrong? I think I'm taking the length of the entire `bb.cocnumber` column here, but how do I make a statement that evaluates each cell of `bb.cocnumber` individually to see if there is a matching 8-digit `aa.cocnumber`?

Comment: If the leading 0 is being cutoff this indicates that you are storing these as numbers and not strings? Personally I wouldn't do this in your join. It will be nonSARGable and horribly inefficient. I would add a computed column (with an index) to your table that holds that correct values. Then you can simply join to it.

Comment: Why you are add `0` instead of just do `LEFT(bb.cocnumber, 8)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I make a statement that evaluates each cell of bb.cocnumber
>   individually to see if there is a matching 8-digit aa.cocnumber?

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` of `bb` to `aa` and check for unmatched rows (and not the other way around):

```
SELECT
  bb.cocnumber
FROM bb LEFT JOIN aa 
ON aa.cocnumber = CASE 
  WHEN LEN(bb.cocnumber) = 12 THEN LEFT(bb.cocnumber, 8)
  WHEN LEN(bb.cocnumber) = 11 THEN '0' + LEFT(bb.cocnumber, 7)
END
WHERE LEN(bb.cocnumber) IN (11, 12) AND aa.cocnumber IS NULL
```

This will return all the `bb.cocnumber`s which after the transformation that you do, do not match any `aa.cocnumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming table `bb` is storing the cocnumber field as an integer, which is why you are missing the leading zeros.

It's easier if you just make them all 12 digits to start with and then take the left 8 chars, then you don't have to worry about case statements:

```
SELECT
aa.cocnumber,
bb.emloyeesnrtotal AS bb_emloyeesnrtotal
FROM aa
LEFT JOIN bb ON aa.cocnumber = LEFT(RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(bb.cocnumber AS VARCHAR), 12), 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to convert the cocnumber from table aa to integer:

```
SELECT
  aa.cocnumber,
  bb.emloyeesnrtotal AS bb_emloyeesnrtotal
FROM aa
  LEFT JOIN bb ON CAST(aa.cocnumber as int) = FLOOR(bb.cocnumber/10000)
```